# Page headers for glossary in arsclassica

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis, small-caps, glossaries-extra, arsclassica

I cannot find a good way of making page headers of `glossaries-extra`’s glossary formatted in ʟᴏᴡᴇʀᴄᴀsᴇ sᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘs that is default format for `arsclassica`’s chapter (i.e, left-hand side pages) and section (i.e, right-hand side pages) marks. I would appreciate some advice in this matter.

In the following MWE, for example, “List of acronyms” in the header is written in a regular sentence case of the `printunsrtglossary`’s `title` key input. However, to stay consistent with the rest of the document, it should be changed to lowercase small caps – like the preceding “ᴛᴇsᴛ ᴄʜᴀᴘᴛᴇʀ” header.

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newacronym{a}{A}{\blindtext[5]}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test chapter}

    \blindtext[6]

    \printunsrtglossary[title={List of~acronyms}]

\end{document}
```

---

[image: Properly formatted page header]

---

[image: Wrongly formatted page header]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `\glsglossarymark`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glsglossarymark}[1]
  {\@mkboth{\textsc\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\textsc\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glsglossarymark}[1]
  {\@mkboth{\textsc\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\textsc\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newacronym{a}{A}{\blindtext[5]}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\blindtext[6]
\printunsrtglossary[title={List of acronyms}]% <- changed
\end{document}
```

[image]